# Google Sheets API Throws 500 Error on Specific Sheet

Tags: c#, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to retrieve information about a spreadsheet. This is how I'm executing the request.

```cs
const string spreadsheetId = "121iA7T1iPiYb5b9srzAbnFPmfNWC5bZ7EnWQWnIVleo";

var request = service
    .Spreadsheets
    .Get(spreadsheetId);

var ranges = new[] {"'Progress'"};
request.Ranges = ranges;
request.IncludeGridData = true;

var result = await request.ExecuteAsync();
```

The `ranges` variable specifies what ranges of the spreadsheet should be taken. This is done via A1 Notation. In the example above, I'm targetting the sheet called `Progress`. In doing so, I retrieve a 500 error.

```
[00:01:29 ERR] Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Internal error encountered. [500]
Errors [
        Message[Internal error encountered.] Location[ - ] Reason[backendError] Domain[global]
]
```

However, if I target the sheet called `Archive` instead (which is on the same spreadsheet), the request works fine and all values are retrieved. The service account has access to both sheets. For interest, here is the spreadsheet I am having issues with: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/121iA7T1iPiYb5b9srzAbnFPmfNWC5bZ7EnWQWnIVleo/edit?usp=sharing

**Edit**
As per @Tanaik's suggestion, I have duplicated the `Progress` sheet. I then renamed the **original** `Progress` sheet to `ProgressOriginal` and renamed the newly duplicated sheet to `Progress`. I **can retrieve the duplicate but not the original, despite them being the exact same sheet content-wise.**

Comment: I think that in that case, when you duplicate the sheet of `Progress` and try it to the duplicated sheet again, what result will you get? Because I'm worry about the possibility of bug.

Comment: The sheet I linked (B) is a copy of the ORIGINAL problem sheet (A). I have the same problem for BOTH A and B

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. I had proposed that when `Progress` sheet in your shared Spreadsheet is duplicated in the same Google Spreadsheet and rename the old `Progress` to others and new copied sheet to `Progress`, and test it again, what result you  will get. In this case, the Google Spreadsheet is not duplicated. A sheet in Google Spreadsheet is duplicated in the same Google Spreadsheet.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike. I renamed Progress to ProgressOriginal and duplicated ProgressOriginal. I then renamed the duplicate to Progress. I can now retrieve the Progress sheet without ANY issue... Do you know why I can't retrieve the original one? The linked spreadsheet shows you the new schema.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could understand that the proposal workaround worked. But unfortunately, I cannot find the clear reason of your issue. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. I would like to study more and more for correctly understanding various situations. I deeply apologize for my poor skill again.

Comment: Dude it's cool, you really helped my anyway. I at least have an idea of what the problem is now. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hey @Tanaike I found something new. I deleted all the rows except for the first two. This fixed the issue and I could retrieve the sheet. However, if I added a completely new and empty third row, the request failed.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I noticed that when I tested your Spreadsheet using Spreadsheet service and the method of values.get and values.batchGet in Sheets API, no error occurs, while the method of get in Sheets API occurs the error. So I thought that this situation might be a bug of the get method. But I'm not sure whether this is the direction you expect. I apologize for this.